# How to use ColorSlider for some objects?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, color

I wrote down some problem, but suddenly have a stuck.
Consider following code :

```
 Manipulate[Graphics[{Orange,Line[{a[{[1]],a[[2]]}],Line[{a[[2]],w}],
 Line[a[[1]],w]}],{Red,Point[w],Point[a[[1]]],Point[a[[2]]]}],
 {{a,{{-1, 0}, {5, 0}}}, Locator}, {w, {0, 5}, {5, 7}]
```

Now I've wanted to change the color of lines with `ColorSlider`. 
Remove `Red` and add `Setting[ColorSlider[Red]]`. But that doesn't get me a `ColorSlider`.

I tried something different, but there was only mistakes. Please give me an example of right writing way!

Sorry for terrible code and (maybe) easy answer. I'm just a newcomer.

Comment: Your code does not run. Please fix syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{col1, Line[a], Line[{a[[2]], w}], Line[{a[[1]], w}],
   col2, PointSize[Large], Point[w], Point[a]}, PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-5, 7}}], 
 {{a, {{-1, 0}, {5, 0}}}, Locator}, {w, {0, 5}, {5, 7}}, 
 {{col1, Orange}, ColorSlider}, {{col2, Red}, ColorSlider}]
```

[image]